# Mysql full text search ignore repeated words take word at once

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I need help in fulltext search in mysql.
I am looking for book named **dreams**. when i search for dreams i got

1. India in my dreams the greatest of all dreams vision
2. Dictionary of dreams - understanding dreams
3. Psyche on dreams & beyond dreams
4. Without dreams
5. Only dreams
6. **Dreams**
7. some other books

Actually i am looking for dreams
How to make 6th book to first one.

I want to ignore repeated words in this case **dreams**.

you can search [here](http://www.sapnaonline.com/index.php?option=com_payment&view=search&filter=title&q=dreams)

I am facing these type of issues in different titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevance of columns with the search word repeated are the higest, The only solution I can see is to do a union query for exact matches with your standard full text search e.g:

```
SELECT * FROM books 
WHERE title = 'Dreams'
UNION
SELECT * FROM books
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST("Dreams")
```

this will show the exact match first.

or you could

```
SELECT * FROM books
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST("Dreams")
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN title = 'Dreams' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),.....
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answers. It will helpful. the problem is performance. we have 10 million books. I tried union previously.. it is taking long time to perform search.. is there any alternative in single query..

Comment: to speed up the equality check in the union you could add a standard index on title, the case when solution would probably be your best bet though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the exact case to be the first suggestion?

Try in order by:

```
"ORDER BY ('{$str_search}' = title) DESC"
```

This will make the exact case searchword you searched for appear first.

2 more solutions:

```
"ORDER BY ('{$str_search}' LIKE title) DESC"
"ORDER BY ('{$str_search}%' LIKE title) DESC"
```

3rd solution can be used to order up all that starts on your search word.

Note: This solution is pretty much the same as the CASE WHEN one.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not relevant anymore, but if anyone comes looking I would reccommend using the levenshtein function on top to solve this. See below for more information and a full implementation in mysql

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40450/mysql-full-text-search-increase-relevance-for-exact-matches

[Levenshtein: MySQL + PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671378/levenshtein-mysql-php)

Answer (score -1):

I can only suggest the usage of regular expressions :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html