# Advance Keyword Search in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In vendor_tbl Tabel i Have Lot of Words  "Microsoft" But when i enter Keyword 'mecrsoft'

or something like this it not return me like micrsoft record and sql query return 0 records

how can to use intelligency to make query That it return me all records like my keyword

below i post sql query in other

any suggetion aur help to make query Better

```
$keyword='mecrsoft';
$mykeyword= explode(" ",$keyword);
for($i=0;$i<count($mykeyword);$i++)
   $keywords_v[]="vendor_name like '%".$mykeyword[$i]."%' or page_description
   like '%".$mykeyword[$i]."%' or  keyword like '%".$mykeyword[$i]."%' or
   page_title like  '%".$mykeyword[$i]."%' or page_description like
   '%".$mykeyword[$i]."%' ";

$q="select vendor_name,slug,page_description,keyword,
   page_title,page_body from vendor_tbl 

where (".implode(',',$keywords_v).")";

$rs=mysql_query($q);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is work for a search engine with an analyser who understand wrong words. For example, ElasticSearch and Fuzzy queries:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/fuzzy-query.html

Or you can use a  levenshtein function in MySQL

[Levenshtein: MySQL + PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671378/levenshtein-mysql-php)

Comment: how to Implemnet Levenshtein in sql query? Becoz i test Soundex function But That Give Same Probelm

Comment: I never to this, sorry. But you can try this: http://kristiannissen.wordpress.com/2010/07/08/mysql-levenshtein/

Answer (score 0):

1. You have data pair of probability terms like 'mecrsoft' mean 'microsoft' or
2. You can implement levenshtein distance algorithm

Comment: How Use levenshtein  in sql Query That fetch Record from tabel Field

Comment: can you tell me how to apply levenshtein distance algorithm  in sql query ?

Comment: @user1138383 Mysql has no levenshtein, but you can create stored function for that. And also, I suggest you to have list of right terms of keywords.