# Improve search result by broadening matches

Tags: php, string-matching

I am trying to improve search result using PHP. e.g. when product name is `ZSX-3185BC` user can not find the product when put something like `ZSX3185BC`. So far i get something like:

```
$input = '01.10-2010';  
$to_replace = array('.','-');
$clean = str_replace($to_replace, '/',$input);`
```

I've tried this, but it does not work correctly *(not sure, posted in comment without elaboration -ed)*

```
$str = ""; 
$len = strlen($strSearch) - 1; 
// Loop through the search string to check each charecter is acceptable and strip those that are not 
for ($i = 0; $i <= $len; $i++) {
    if(preg_match("/\w|-| /",$strSearch[$i])) {
        $str = $str . $strSearch[$i]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: would you like to get the search results replacing special charaters directly in mysql query?

Comment: show some exact code what your tried.

Comment: `$str = "";
$len = strlen($strSearch) - 1;
// Loop through the search string to check each charecter is acceptable and strip those that are not
 For ($i = 0; $i <= $len; $i++)
 {
  if(preg_match("/\w|-| /",$strSearch[$i]))
  {
   $str = $str . $strSearch[$i];
    }
 }`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do this kind of fuzzy matching directly in your database query. A common approach to fuzzy string matching is the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

MySQL does not have this built in, however, it can be added. [See this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671378/levenshtein-mysql-php)

The basic way is to add a stored function to MySQL. There is a [Levenshtein implementation](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552) as a stored function.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE replace(fieldname, '-', '') like '%ZSX3185BC%';
```

Comment: This will force a full table scan and cannot use any indices.

Comment: And `SELECT *` is poor practice -- specify columns. I know you don't know columns in this case (not provided), but just don't type the star!

Comment: i just gave the example, and he is able to specify the columns he wants.