# PHP - Optimization - Levenshtein distance with prioritization

Tags: php, optimization, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to implement the [levenshtein algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) with a little addon. I want to prioritize values that have consecutive matching letters. I've tried implementing my own form of it using the code below:

```
function levenshtein_rating($string1, $string2) {
    $GLOBALS['lvn_memo'] = array();
    return lev($string1, 0, strlen($string1), $string2, 0, strlen($string2));
}

function lev($s1, $s1x, $s1l, $s2, $s2x, $s2l, $cons = 0) {
    $key = $s1x . "," . $s1l . "," . $s2x . "," . $s2l;
    if (isset($GLOBALS['lvn_memo'][$key])) return $GLOBALS['lvn_memo'][$key];

    if ($s1l == 0) return $s2l;
    if ($s2l == 0) return $s1l;

    $cost = 0;
    if ($s1[$s1x] != $s2[$s2x]) $cost = 1;
    else $cons -= 0.1;

    $dist = min(
                (lev($s1, $s1x + 1, $s1l - 1, $s2, $s2x, $s2l, $cons) + 1), 
                (lev($s1, $s1x, $s1l, $s2, $s2x + 1, $s2l - 1, $cons) + 1), 
                (lev($s1, $s1x + 1, $s1l - 1, $s2, $s2x + 1, $s2l - 1, $cons) + $cost)
            );
    $GLOBALS['lvn_memo'][$key] = $dist + $cons;
    return $dist + $cons;
}
```

You should note the `$cons -= 0.1;` is the part where I am adding a value to prioritize consecutive values. This formula will be checking against a large database of strings. (As high as 20,000 - 50,000) I've done a benchmark test with PHP's built in `levenshtein`

```
Message      Time Change     Memory
PHP          N/A             9300128
End PHP      1ms             9300864
End Mine     20ms            9310736
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2.5
    [1] => 1.9
    [2] => -1.5
)
```

Benchmark Test Code:

```
$string1 = "kitten";
$string2 = "sitter";
$string3 = "sitting";

$log = new Logger("PHP");
$distances = array();
$distances[] = levenshtein($string1, $string3);
$distances[] = levenshtein($string2, $string3);
$distances[] = levenshtein($string3, $string3);
$log->log("End PHP");

$distances2 = array();
$distances2[] = levenshtein_rating($string1, $string3);
$distances2[] = levenshtein_rating($string2, $string3);
$distances2[] = levenshtein_rating($string3, $string3);
$log->log("End Mine");
echo $log->status();

echo "<pre>" . print_r($distances, true) . "</pre>";
echo "<pre>" . print_r($distances2, true) . "</pre>";
```

I recognize that PHP's built in function will probably always be faster than mine by nature. But I am wondering if there is a way to speed mine up?

So the question: Is there a way to speed this up? My alternative here is to run levenshtein and then search through the highest X results of that and prioritize them additionally.

---

Based on Leigh's comment, copying PHP's built in form of Levenhstein lowered the time down to 3ms. (EDIT: Posted the version with consecutive character deductions. This may need tweaked, by appears to work.)

```
function levenshtein_rating($s1, $s2, $cons = 0, $cost_ins = 1, $cost_rep = 1, $cost_del = 1) {
    $s1l = strlen($s1);
    $s2l = strlen($s2);
    if ($s1l == 0) return $s2l;
    if ($s2l == 0) return $s1l;

    $p1 = array();
    $p2 = array();

    for ($i2 = 0; $i2 <= $s2l; ++$i2) {
        $p1[$i2] = $i2 * $cost_ins;
    }

    $cons = 0;
    $cons_count = 0;
    $cln = 0;
    $tbl = $s1;
    $lst = false;

    for ($i1 = 0; $i1 < $s1l; ++$i1) {
        $p2[0] = $p1[0] + $cost_del;

        $srch = true;

        for($i2 = 0; $i2 < $s2l; ++ $i2) {
            $c0 = $p1[$i2] + (($s1[$i1] == $s2[$i2]) ? 0 : $cost_rep);
            if ($srch && $s2[$i2] == $tbl[$i1]) {
                $tbl[$i1] = "\0";
                $srch = false;
                $cln += ($cln == 0) ? 1 : $cln * 1;
            }

            $c1 = $p1[$i2 + 1] + $cost_del;

            if ($c1 < $c0) $c0 = $c1;
            $c2 = $p2[$i2] + $cost_ins;
            if ($c2 < $c0) $c0 = $c2;

            $p2[$i2 + 1] = $c0;
        }

        if (!$srch && $lst) {
            $cons_count += $cln;
            $cln = 0;
        }
        $lst = $srch;

        $tmp = $p1;
        $p1 = $p2;
        $p2 = $tmp;
    }
    $cons_count += $cln;

    $cons = -1 * ($cons_count * 0.1);
    return $p1[$s2l] + $cons;
}
```

Comment: This should probably go to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). And we need your test data input and output: Which strings are compared, and what is the function result?

Comment: Posted the test code sample.

Comment: I should also mention that cutting out the `else $cons -= 0.1;` has no impact on the benchmark.

Comment: You have another option. If you are in control of your own servers and able to run a custom PHP binary, it should be fairly trivial to implement your modified levenshtein function as a core PHP function.

Comment: @Leigh - This is a good suggestion. However, I don't think that the customers are going to allow me to do that. I'll research more into this.

Comment: @Tom Well you can always offer them both, the native solution, and another as a PHP extension (and give them the source and let them compile it themselves). Extension writing is easier than I expected, there's a few hidden gems on it out on the net, and you'd literally have to copy/paste the existing levenshtein code and give it a different name + your tweaks.

Comment: [You could mimic PHPs own implementation](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/levenshtein.c#30). Function calls in PHP are notoriously expensive. Your recursive function is generating a lot of overhead. If you can turn it into a loop (as PHP does it), you should definitely see an improvement in performance. [You can also implement it directly on MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671378/levenshtein-mysql-php)

Comment: @Leight: The strings are going to be less than 30 to 40 characters. (Typically 5 - 10) I'll have a benchmark test with MySQL's and see how she blows. I think in my mind I am prejudice against MySQL performance wise. We'll see what the math says though. Scanning through PHP's stuff now. If it's relying entirely on the pointers, I might not be able to replicate. (Working on it now.)

Comment: @Leight: I implemented a form of PHP's from what you posted and it is down to 3 ms! I can post code, but don't want to take your possible answer rep? I also will have to review this so I understand what is happening so I can append my thing.

Comment: @Tom haha, I was also implementing it out of curiosity. I will post mine and we can compare notes :)

Comment: Posted my version in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the major slowdown in your function is the fact that it's recursive.

As I've said in my comments, PHP function calls are notoriously heavy work for the engine.

PHP itself implements `levenshtein` as a loop, keeping a running total of the cost incurred for inserts, replacements and deletes.

I'm sure if you converted your code to a loop as well you'd see some massive performance increases.

I don't know exactly what your code is doing, but I have ported the native C code to PHP to give you a starting point.

```
define('LEVENSHTEIN_MAX_LENGTH', 12);

function lev2($s1, $s2, $cost_ins = 1, $cost_rep = 1, $cost_del = 1)
{
    $l1 = strlen($s1);
    $l2 = strlen($s2);

    if ($l1 == 0) {
        return $l2 * $cost_ins;
    }
    if ($l2 == 0) {
        return $l1 * $cost_del;
    }

    if (($l1 > LEVENSHTEIN_MAX_LENGTH) || ($l2 > LEVENSHTEIN_MAX_LENGTH)) {
        return -1;
    }

    $p1 = array();
    $p2 = array();

    for ($i2 = 0; $i2 <= $l2; $i2++) {
        $p1[$i2] = $i2 * $cost_ins;
    }

    for ($i1 = 0; $i1 < $l1; $i1++) {
        $p2[0] = $p1[0] + $cost_del;

        for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < $l2; $i2++) {
            $c0 = $p1[$i2] + (($s1[$i1] == $s2[$i2]) ? 0 : $cost_rep);
            $c1 = $p1[$i2 + 1] + $cost_del;
            if ($c1 < $c0) {
                $c0 = $c1;
            }
            $c2 = $p2[$i2] + $cost_ins;
            if ($c2 < $c0) {
                $c0 = $c2;
            }
            $p2[$i2 + 1] = $c0;
        }
        $tmp = $p1;
        $p1 = $p2;
        $p2 = $tmp;
    }
    return $p1[$l2];
}
```

I did a quick benchmark comparing yours, mine, and PHPs internal functions, 100,000 iterations each, time is in seconds.

```
float(12.954766988754)
float(2.4660499095917)
float(0.14857912063599)
```

Obviously it hasn't got your tweaks in it yet, but I'm sure they wont slow it down that much.

If you really need more of a speed boost, once you have worked out how to change this function, it should be easy enough to port your changes back into C, make a copy of PHPs function definitions, and implement your own native C version of your modified function.

There's lots of tutorials out there on how to make PHP extensions, so you shouldn't have that much difficulty if you decide to go down that route.

**Edit:**

Was looking at ways to improve it further, I noticed

```
        $c0 = $p1[$i2] + (($s1[$i1] == $s2[$i2]) ? 0 : $cost_rep);
        $c1 = $p1[$i2 + 1] + $cost_del;
        if ($c1 < $c0) {
            $c0 = $c1;
        }
        $c2 = $p2[$i2] + $cost_ins;
        if ($c2 < $c0) {
            $c0 = $c2;
        }
```

Is the same as

```
        $c0 = min(
            $p1[$i2 + 1] + $cost_del,
            $p1[$i2] + (($s1[$i1] == $s2[$i2]) ? 0 : $cost_rep),
            $c2 = $p2[$i2] + $cost_ins
        );
```

Which I think directly relates to the `min` block in your code. However, this **slows down** the code quite significantly. (I guess its the overhead of the extra function call)

Benchmarks with the `min()` block as the second timing.

```
float(2.484846830368)
float(3.6055288314819)
```

You were right about the second `$cost_ins` not belonging - copy/paste fail on my part.

Comment: Is your benchmark comparing the port I posted in my question or the original? I think we have the same thing for the port. (Just clarifying.)

Comment: Also, I don't think `$p1[$i2] = $i2 * $cost_ins;` belongs in the second for loop, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: It was comparing with your original, removed the superfluous `$cost_ins` statement, my fault for copy/pasting the first for loop, thanks. Looks like we had pretty much the same thing in the end :)

Comment: How did the performance turn out with your modifications added?

Comment: I'm reworking them, they don't work in every case. I'll post when it's complete.

Comment: I've updated my code. It's a bit confusing, but I think that PHP's implementation does Levenshtein a little bit differently. I'm not sure if that's true or how, but I know that it compares each letter of st1 against every letter of str2. (So K VS S, K VS I, K VS T, K VS T, K VS I, K VS N, K VS G.) This makes it a bit confusing to track consecutive numbers, so I added a table to check against. When it matches, it removes the character. Consecutive values have higher significance. I need to test this in a real situation to make sure it doesn't blur out other relevant results though.