# MySQL fulltext: have a result weigh more

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a database of cities and states (about 43,000). I do a full text search on it like so:

```
select city, state, match(city, state_short, state) against (:q in boolean mode) as score
from zipcodes where
match(city, state_short, state) against (:q in boolean mode)
group by city, state order by score desc limit 6
```

When I replace `:q` with a meaningful string, it works, but lets say I search for `houston texas`, I would like the result to be first, but instead it is 3rd:

- `North Houston, Texas`
- `South Houston, Texas`
- `Houston, Texas`

How can I make `Houston, Texas` weigh more than the other 2? This obviously should be the same for other cities like this as well.

**Edit**

This works, any thoughts on it?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT city, state, MATCH(city, state_short, state) AGAINST (:q IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score
    FROM zipcodes
    WHERE MATCH(city, state_short, state) AGAINST (:q IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    GROUP BY city, state
    ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 6
) AS tbl
ORDER BY score DESC, LENGTH(city)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your new query may work, but it is entirely circumstantial.  Instead of doing `ORDER BY LENGTH(city)`, something like `ORDER BY ABS(LENGTH(:q) - (LENGTH(city) + LENGTH(state)))` would be better.  This isn't perfect, but it should be better since anything having the same length as the input and a high score is probably what you're looking for.  The final query would look something like this:

```
SELECT city, state, MATCH(city, state_short, state) AGAINST (:q IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
FROM zipcodes
WHERE MATCH(city, state_short, state) AGAINST (:q IN BOOLEAN MODE)
GROUP BY city, state
ORDER BY score DESC, ABS(LENGTH(:q) - (LENGTH(city) + LENGTH(state))) DESC LIMIT 6
```

I moved the new `ORDER BY` clause into the main query to remove the subquery.  This should yield the same (or possibly more accurate) results.

The Levenshtein Distance would probably be a more accurate measure for this, but there is no native implementation of it in MySQL.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671378/levenshtein-mysql-php) has more information about a MySQL implementation of a Levenshtein Distance function.