# Subtract two strings in PHP or mySQL to count differences

Tags: php, mysql, string

Is it possible to return the number of characters which differ between two strings?

In my case, I would like to run a check to quantify how much a user's draft has changed vs the database version. With this information, the system can decide weather or not the draft needs to be auto-saved.

For example:

```
echo string_diff("Hello world", "Hi World");
```

This should output "5", indicating that characters "ello" & "W" are different.

Is this possible with PHP? How about with mySQL?

Comment: have a look at [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)

Comment: or as simple as http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php or substr_compare and co...

Comment: also levenshtein function with mysql [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671378/levenshtein-mysql-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the PHP side your options are

1. [**similar_text**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) which calculates the percent similarity between two strings
2. [**levenshtein**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) - which calculates the edit distance between two strings (the number of key strokes it takes to transform string a into string b)

on mysql you can use [this](https://github.com/MartinZottmann/mysql-levenshtein) user defined function to calculate the levenshtein distance