# Displaying accuracy of MySQL SELECT queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What is the best way to build a MySQL query so as to:

1. Display only 100% match if it exists (one row will be returned) or, if there isn't a 100% match,
2. Display other entries with different accuracies (many rows returned, but not entries with 0% accuracy).

The results should resemble something like that:

`SELECT Green Mile FROM books`

Results:
Green Mile | 100%

`SELECT Green Road FROM books`

Results:
Green Mile | 50% 
Winding Road | 50% 
Greet Me | 20%

I am not providing any database schema as I will be grateful to receive general advice about how I could achieve similar results quering a database. I should add that queries and output are constructed in PHP.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you define "100%" match?  How do you define partial matches?

Comment: You can't (easily) do that sort of thing in MySQL.  I guess you're wanting some sort of "weighting" - look at Levenstein Functions - try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671378/levenshtein-mysql-php

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I define 100% match when the term searched for exists in a database in its entirety - exactly word for word. Partial match shoudl be calculated based on the number of matching characters in the searched term v. database entries. @splig I was hoping for a simpler solution. Mayby SQL `MATCH`..`AGAINST`?

Comment: fulltext searches can give you a relevance score, but the number you get back is somewhat arbitrary. if you want percentages, you'll have to do the work yourself.