# Can I know the accuracy of a MySQL full-text search result?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I want to know if I can get for example a percentage of accuracy in my query result; for example something like this:

query:

```
"I love stackoverflow"
```

Results: (result, accuracy)

```
"we love stackoverflow",   80%
"I hate stackoverflow" ,   70%
"They hate stackoverflow", 40%
```

If there is nothing like this in MySQL full-text search, can you recommend me a text search library that can easily be deployed in an existing project in MYSQL DB and PHP?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html look for "relevance"

Comment: so question similar -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646260/displaying-accuracy-of-mysql-select-queries

Comment: @MarcB I understand that MySQL order results by "relevance" but you know how to display that relevance for each row in the query result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FULLTEXT` has this.

The value of

```
MATCH (col1,col2) AGAINST ('matching terms')
```

(when used in a SELECT or ORDER BY statement) produces the relevance score. It's not a percentage score, but it is a metric showing how close the match is to the terms.

For example,

```
 select zip, 
       primary_city, 
       match(primary_city, acceptable_cities) against ('york') AS relevance
  from zip
  where match(primary_city, acceptable_cities) against ('york') 
 order by 3 desc
```

produces the relevance of a match to a postcode table.