# how to select from table where row is similar but not exactly same for to include misspeling?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

For examle my table at MySQL has values like;

```
>  Foobar is cool
>  foobar was in here
>  Bla bla bla
```

I need result where search text is "foobar" even if user misspelled as "fobar"

```
   >  Foobar is cool
   >  foobar was in here
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no spell checker built into mysql.  So you would need to use something similar to the following:  SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'f%bar' OR column LIKE 'f%ar'... etc.

Comment: i read some articles about levenshtein and similar_text() functions. I am not sure but  these may helps for solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a levenshtein function which returns the minimal number of character changes needed to transform one word into another word.

One implementation is shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4671557/5546380

This example just compares two words so you'd need to either modify this function or create a new one that calls this one and performs the levenshtein on each word within the field and return if it passes a certain threshold, for example 1 character change for "fobar" to be "foobar", 2 for "foba" to be "foobar".