# search without hyphen in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql database contains below kind of values :

`'AE01-1056 Ricoh Aficio'` OR `'Ricoh AE01-1087 (AE01-1069)'` etc

AS if am a normal user i will search the product name in simple text like

AE011056 ... but the result is not found.

i hav tried this query:

```
$q="SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (p.product_name LIKE '$name%' OR c.category_name LIKE '$name%' OR pm.name LIKE '$name%')";
```

What change should i make in my query to get the product , because i have tried LIKE operator & it's not working for me.

Comment: You should also use prepared statements for a query that accepts user input.  Otherwise you're opening yourself up to SQL injections.

Comment: Read here more for complex lookup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671378/levenshtein-mysql-php#4671557

Comment: Thank you @tim , but actually the query is in prepared statement.. but just for simplicity i wrote here like this .

Comment: hi neha... I just gave you some reputation... I'd be happy if you return the favor :p

Answer (score 3):

Use replace function

```
$q="SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE (REPLACE(p.product_name,'-','') LIKE '%$name%' 
       OR REPLACE(c.category_name,'-','') LIKE '%$name%'
       OR REPLACE(pm.name ,'-','') LIKE '%$name%')";
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this will render useless any index on these columns.

Comment: thanks @hkutluay, I have tried this also, but not working for me  :(

Comment: yes @hkutluay, i have checked now only.... right now my query is like this :: (p.product_name LIKE '$name%' OR REPLACE('p.product_name','-','') LIKE '%$name' OR c.category_name LIKE '$name%' OR pm.name LIKE '$name%')

Comment: because c.category name and pm.name does not contain hyphen.

Comment: @nehachaukikar ok i see.. you should also use two % after like operator. Like '%$name%'. Because you search text not only begining of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are only two ways:

**1. Manipulate search string**
If you knwo, users are often search for a code and don't use nessesary hyphens, check the searchstring bevor searching if it follows a given format an insert the hypen if it is missing.

**2. replace all hyphens in the where-statement**
see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Depending on your setup, solution one might be the more performant solution, since you only have to do one instead multiple stringmanipulations.