# Smart search in mysql php for one word

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on searching part, I am facing one issue for searching records. I have products table having columns like :- *id, product_name*

```
id   product_name
 1    woodpecker handpiece
 2    hand piece
```

Now I when search with query="woo" it's searching fine. When I add query="wooo"   Now next time if I search query="woooooooo" its fine if user enters many o's. I want at least if user enters by mistake 2(o's) then it must search.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE '%woo%'; //its working fine

SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE '%woooo%'; //its not working fine.
```

My client gives some reference site where its working I am not sure how the
doing. This reference image :-

[image]

See above image I have entered wrong query 'wooo'.. its still searching
Please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671378/levenshtein-mysql-php

Comment: use `soundex()`;

Comment: soundex not working

Comment: @Dharman its showing FUNCTION mydatabase.levenshtein does not exist

Comment: That is because you haven't read the answer in full...

Comment: @Dharman how to add this code and where can you help me?

Comment: The reason why I linked it as duplicate is because it is already explained there in details and I didn't want to waste time to explain it again. `SOUNDEX` should suffice, but if it is not enough follow the linked guide.

Comment: @Dharman when i am importing file its showing this error :- 
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Comment: Did you change the delimiters? `DELIMITER @` and then back to `;`

Comment: i copy and paste the first funtion in one sql fie 
http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=552

Comment: Wrap that code with the `DELIMITER` statements. Put `DELIMITER @` before and put `DELIMITER ;` after. If you can't make this work, google how to create stored procedures in mysql

Comment: @Dharman i have successfully imported the sql query but query runs fine but result is not coming.. can you help me?

Comment: My sql query is SELECT `product_name` FROM `products` WHERE levenshtein('wooo', 'product_name') BETWEEN 0 AND 4
but not returning data

Answer (score 4):

this will work:

```
select * from table1 where soundex(product_name)=soundex('wooooooodpecker handpiece');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59e340/4

One of the many MySQL string functions is the SOUNDEX() function. This function returns a Soundex string from a given string. If two words sound the same, they should have the same Soundex string. If two words sound similar, but not exactly the same, their Soundex string might look similar but not exactly the same.

is this what you want:

```
select * from table1 where 
soundex(substring(product_name,1,3))=soundex(substring('woooooo',1,3));
```

check;http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59e340/22

Comment: empty data is coming

Comment: @kunal Show us what your full query looks like now

Comment: select * from products where soundex(product_name)=soundex('wooo');

Comment: @nikhilsugandh i don't get

Comment: @nikhilsugandh its not searching when i add wooo in string

Comment: strange why you guys take "wooooooodpecker handpiece" this string my question input is different

Comment: @kunal `woodpecker handpiece` should match with  `wooooooodpecker handpiece`  any o's woodpecker this is what you wanted!!!

Comment: I want when I search with this string 'wooo' then woodpecker will come but you added the wooooodpecker handpeice in string

Comment: @nikhilsugandh is it working for middle words as well????. suppose my word is "Wool Check Cushion Fawn Blue"   and i enter the query as per your answer
select * from table1 where 
soundex(substring(product_name,1,3))=soundex(substring('fawnnnn',1,3));   
its not working if enter the word from middle

Comment: @nikhilsugandh have you got my problem?

Comment: @kunal give it a thumbs up